# Default /logout doesn't work when securityMatcher used in Spring Security 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

In Spring Security 6, (specifically Spring Boot 3.2, Spring MVC with Thymeleaf in my case) when securityMatcher is used, the default /logout POST or GET stops working.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain openFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher("/EParticipate/baudit/**")
            .addFilterBefore(new BauditUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(
                this.authenticationManager(userDetailsService, passwordEncoder())),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
            )
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/EParticipate/baudit/**").hasRole("BAUDIT")
                .requestMatchers("/EParticipateSecurity/**").permitAll()
            )
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager(userDetailsService, passwordEncoder()))
            .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/EParticipateSecurity/login_request").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/EParticipate/baudit")
            )
        return http.build();
    }
```

and POST link in Thymeleaf:

```
    <form id="logout_form" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
         <button id="logout_button" type="submit">Logout</button>
    </form>
```

Even if you add a `permitAll()` to a requestMatcher, it still won't work:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain openFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher("/EParticipate/baudit/**")
            .addFilterBefore(new BauditUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(
                this.authenticationManager(userDetailsService, passwordEncoder())),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
            )
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/EParticipate/baudit/**").hasRole("BAUDIT")
                //Doesn't work
                .requestMatchers("/EParticipateSecurity/**","/logout").permitAll()
            )
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager(userDetailsService, passwordEncoder()))
            .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/EParticipateSecurity/login_request").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/EParticipate/baudit")
            )
        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I had to add a custom logout as a child URL under the URL of the securityMatcher (I also added a logout handler to make sure everything was cleared on logout).

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain openFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher("/EParticipate/baudit/**")
        .addFilterBefore(new BauditUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(
            this.authenticationManager(userDetailsService, passwordEncoder())),
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
        )
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/EParticipate/baudit/**").hasRole("BAUDIT")
            .requestMatchers("/EParticipateSecurity/**").permitAll()
        )
        .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager(userDetailsService, passwordEncoder()))
        .formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/EParticipateSecurity/login_request").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/EParticipate/baudit")
        )
        .logout((logout) -> logout
            .addLogoutHandler(new HeaderWriterLogoutHandler(new ClearSiteDataHeaderWriter(Directive.CACHE,Directive.COOKIES,Directive.EXECUTION_CONTEXTS,Directive.STORAGE)))
            .logoutUrl("/EParticipate/baudit/logout")//URL under the securityMatcher URL above
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/EParticipateSecurity/login_request").permitAll()
        );
    return http.build();
}
```